# How to add custom text highlight into the editor?

Tags: nitrousio

I have succeeded to compile demo web application using OCaml and Ocsigen server but it's tricky to edit *.eliom, *.eliomi, *.ml and *.mli files because there is no syntax for OCaml. Erlang seems to be best option but it has some issues comparately to OCaml syntax. Can I add new syntax definition myself or I should ask developers about it?

Comment: This is more of a question for their support team, but you can't add any new syntax definitions at this time. I'll let the dev team know about your request though to see if we can add it in a future update.

Comment: @gman, Any news about this issue? Maybe syntax highlight definitions file is not so complex and I contribute it myself?

Comment: No updates as of yet. We will prioritize updating the Web IDE editor as a whole, so there may be many big changes yet to come. If you are running Win/Mac I would suggest taking a look at Nitrous Desktop ( https://www.nitrous.io/desktop ). This will allow you to sync your work locally, and from there you could edit with Sublime Text or which ever text editor you prefer.